# How to add a template to a discord bot repl

Tags: discord, bots, replit

I have a template for making a Talking Discord Bot Through ChatGPT on OpenAI, And I have the basic template it gives you when you select "Discord Bot Python" when creating a replit. And I don't know how to add the OpenAI Template to the Discord Bot File. This is all done on Replit btw.

I've tried looking all around to see any buttons for it I couldn't find any.